# What's the right verb and tense?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

> There **would be** a time where **you would** constantly ask every person you
>   ***have* encountered** how near the summit is.

The sentence is in the form where I constantly observe people in every climbing asking about the distance of the summit.

Comment: My first impulse is to change it to _had_, but my second impulse is to remove the word entirely. I think that makes the sentence make the most sense.

Comment: @eelero after removing have, is the word encounter should be in what tense? thank you

Comment: @ArkeiAraullo past tense, just like it already is.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be mixing your tenses.

Your sentence seems to be giving advice to someone who is considering a climb in the future, and as they get closer to the top

> There *will* be a time *when* you *will* constantly *be asking* every person you *encounter* how close the summit is.

Stylistically, I might change it to

> There will come a time when you will ask every person you come across how far it is to the summit.

If you wanted to place your original sentence it in the past, as if the climber used to do this

> There *was* a time *when* you would constantly ask every person you *had* encountered how near the summit *was*.

which might imply they may no longer do this since they are more experienced.

Comment: This is a good answer.  Just to add to it, "would" implies that the situation is imaginary, uncertain, or unlikely.  For example,"I would climb the mountain if I could only get some time off."  "Will" is more certain.  If you want to maintain the uncertainty, you could say something like "There may come a time when you ask every person you meet how far it is to the summit."    It all depends on what you want to say.